# How to Expand Existing My.Settings StringCollection Array

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

I'm a bit rusty and am updating a VB.Net program I wrote in 2013 using VS2017. I needed to expand a My.Settings StringCollection array by one entry. It was User scope, and I could not figure out how to enlarge the existing array, despite hours of online research and testing.

I tried using the .Add method, but was told "not a member of String." I tried deleting "user.config."

Finally I tried this, which worked:
1) At design time, in Settings, I added the extra placeholder value to my StringCollection variable.
2) Change the scope from User to Application.
3) Run the program.
4) Change the scope back to User.
I confirmed this worked by inspecting My.Settings at runtime.
What I want to know is:
Why did this work, and is there a more elegant way to have done this?

```
    For index = 0 To 5 'Motor numbers
        'Changing upper index limit from 4 to 5 throws an Exception 
        strCommand = "(0," & index.ToString & ")"
        My.Settings.strMotor_Kp(index) = (Kpid(0, index))
        strCommand = "(1," & index.ToString & ")"
        My.Settings.strMotor_Ki(index) = (Kpid(1, index))
        strCommand = "(2," & index.ToString & ")"
        My.Settings.strMotor_Kd(index) = (Kpid(2, index))
    Next
```

Comment: How are you creating New Specialized.StringCollection and saving it?

Comment: I never used the New method. The StringCollection (e.g., My.Settings.strMotor_Kp) was originally created in 2013 by making 5 entries via MyProject|Settings. All I wanted to do (and did, using the method described) was to expand it to 6 entries. I added the 6th entry as described.

Answer (score 1):

The StringCollection editor is quite a bit limited, you can append lines easily but insert one in the middle is not possible to my knowledge.

But you can also change the values in `app.config`, recompile the project and then open the settings, then VS is going to asks you

> Value of setting 'Foo' was changed in the app.config file. ... Do you
>   want to update the value in the .settings file?

The whole thing should work without having to switch the setting to application- and back to user mode. Just compile it and then the changes are reflected in the `app.config` (the `user.config` is generated at runtime when method Save() is called).

Only if the project namespace has changed, then the old entries must be deleted from `app.config` prior to recompiling the project, or the namespace must be adjusted in the `<[...].Properties.Settings>` tag).

Comment: All of my variables, created in 2013 using MyProject|Settings, were designated "user scope," and none as "application scope." As I understand it, this means that none of the entries in app.config were ever used until I toggled the variables of interest to application scope and back. (As an aside, I see no reason I could not use my method to manually "insert" a new value anywhere in the existing StringCollection array, not just append it to the end of the array.)

Comment: @petercat How about creating a new one, adding current things to it, add new thing, then save it on place of old one?

Comment: @petercat: No, they are reflected in the app.config anyway, as the user settings are taken from it if they don't exist.

Comment: CruleD: I think your suggestion to create a new one would work. I just want to see if I can avoid the extra effort, and use the legacy data. After all, a legacy StringCollection array could be quite large in some applications, increasing the risk of typos.

Comment: @Christoph: What you say is true, but in the challenge I'm posing the user settings do exist (I don't want to lose them, or re-enter them, as CruleD suggests).